# How to validate single form split in two tabs and save the scope data after validation success angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I have form split in two tabs and submit button is present on the second tab.Elements in both the tabs are present enclosed within same form tag and share same "ng-controller".Problem is I can submit the form without filling form elements in the first tab and it shows error  scope object is undefined.How do I validate the form elements in this case and save the scope data on pressing submit.Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your validation problem, you'll want to validate that each required field has been filled-out correctly before acting on the submit. What I would do: instead of the submit button directly calling the submit functionality, it would call a function that checks for all the necessary values on the scope, and if it works, then it calls the submit function.

With regards to saving the data, you'll either want to save it to a db or store it temporarily in a service.This is a pretty good tutorial on services: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/